# Android getChildFragmentManager() level API < 17

Tags: android

I am trying to use getChildFragmentManager() method on api 14, but of course I am getting error. Is there anyway to use this method on lower apis.
Thanks

Comment: use `getSupportChildFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To use nested fragments on API Level 16 and below, you need to use the fragments backport from the `support-v4` or `support-v13` portion of the Android Support package. This, in turn, requires you to inherit from `FragmentActivity` and have your fragments inherit from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Then, you can [call `getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) to use nested fragments.

Comment: do you mean getChildFragmentManager() is supported on api 14 if i have imported android.support.v4.app.Fragment to my fragment?

Comment: @dondonhk: I think so. I am having a bit of difficulty understanding your question. If you are inheriting from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, and using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`, you have access to a working implementation of `getChildFragmentManager()`. With native fragments (`android.app.Fragment`), `getChildFragmentManager()` is only available on API Level 17 and higher.

Comment: ooops... sorry for my poor english :/ .... 
anyways thanks, I made it working on my api 14 emulator now...

Answer (score 4):

To someone that appeared here by a search on Google

I was having a similar problem using DialogFragment

The problem was because I was importing `android.app.DialogFragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`

DialogFragment or not, be sure that you are importing the right libs :)