# Can a fragment be a host to a view pager instead of an activity?

Tags: android, tabs

Can a view pager be put in a fragment's layout, so this fragment would be the host to a few other fragments? So far I've seen only Activities as a host.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, use the code bellow

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
}
```

view the full implementation here https://github.com/marcoRS/nested-fragments/tree/master/src/com/burnside/digital/nestedfragments

Comment: getChiledFragmentManager only works in api > 17.
I currently use 16, is there any way to overcome that issue without changing all my fragments to v4( because getSupportChildFragment will require from me to switch all my fragments to v4 (but that's not realistic to change them all as I have a huge amount of them and they're all native)

Comment: You are supporting a really old API version, it is almost dead, switch for API17 or + and don't spend time learning something that will disappear soon... take a look here http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: BTW, I found the way to do for API<17 but do not recommend as I said...
check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595388/android-getchildfragmentmanager-level-api-17

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Here is an example (Use TabHost inside a Fragment with a ViewPager):

```
    public class GroupFragment extends Fragment {

    private static TabLayout tabLayout;
    private static ViewPager viewPager;
    private static final int int_items = 4 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                   }
        });

        return x;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position){
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new PrimaryFragment();
                case 1 : return new SocialFragment();
                case 2 : return new UpdatesFragment();
                case 3 : return new TeamFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Grupo A";
                case 1 :
                    return "Grupo B";
                case 2 :
                    return "Grupo C";
                case 3:
                    return "Grupo D";
            }
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

And the Layout of the fragment is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: TabLayout cannot be replaced with PagerTabStrip for tab indication?

Comment: Yes, you can replace it.

Comment: I have a problem with getChildFragmentManager(). It says it requires min api 17. (I'm on 16)

Comment: Use getSupportChildFragmentManager().

Comment: but my fragments are native , not v4

Comment: Try change to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: but all my other fragments are native. Won't it cause issues if on the same activity all fragments are native but one fragment is v4 ?

Comment: actually I can't .. because then I would have to change the fragment before that one to v4, and the one before that on to v4 as well, and so on and on..

Comment: There is no problem if you change all your fragments to v4

Comment: I have a lot.. around 80 , I don't want to change all of the project now.. too bad there isn't any other way