# getChildFragmentManager in a fragment in level API 17 <

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to put a ViewPager inside a DialogFragment, and as far I know `getChildFragmentManager()` is only available from API 17 and above, and the minSDK in the app is 16. Is there any way to do use a ViewPager in a DialogFragment without using getChildFragmentManager?

PS: Increasing the minSDK is not possible.

Comment: It all should be available if you use the support library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595388/android-getchildfragmentmanager-level-api-17

Comment: In other words, use `android.support.v4.app.DialogManager` instead of `android.app.DialogManager`.

Comment: I though I was using it, well, anyways, that was the problem, now works like a charm, thanks.